# CRM 2013 Cannot retrieve new entity after creation in console application

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In console application program I connect to CRM and update entity

The updating (in CRM) start plugin that create new record in another entity

Then in console application I'm trying to get the record that the plugin created (whith linq or fetch)

but i can not, i get null although I see the new record in CRM (while debugging and after it)

(I am sure that retrieve is correct because in the next time that I run the console it's returns to me the right line that created in the first time.
as I understand it is a problem with the transaction)

```
 ...  
 entityA["doctor"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactId); 
// update the first entity   
 XrmService.Update(entityA);  
 entityBB entityB = new entityBB(); 
// retrieve the record that the plugin created   
entityB = (from emp in XrmService.Xrm.entityBSet
                                   where ...)
                                   select new entityBB  
                                   { 
                                       Id = emp.Id
                                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then i get entityB null although I see that the record created

adding all linq statment:

```
 instituteEmployees = (from emp in XrmService.Xrm.el_instituteemployeeSet
                                      where ((emp.el_institute.Id == institute || emp.el_LicenseId.Id == licenseId) &&
                                      emp.el_contact == license.moha_acting_doctor && emp.el_JOB == instJob.ToEntityReference())
                                      select new el_instituteemployee
                                      {  
                                          Id = emp.Id,

                                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Are you mixing early bound with late bound? If not, what is "emp".

Comment: Is the XrmService a Plugin context?  I was not aware that you could perform an update on an entity reference as well.  Would also like to see your entire linq statement.

Comment: XrmService is IOrganizationService (I added up linq statement) , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the case where it works sometimes and not others, it is probably due to a race condition.  My best guest without seeing any code or how the Plugin is registered, is that the Plugin is running asynchronously.  If you want to ensure that it exists, register it as synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the Plugin register as synchronous (I tried Pre operation and it didnt help) so that's not the problem.